# Configure log4js logger to log only INFO to console and everything to file

Tags: node.js, logging, log4js-node

With below-mentioned [log4js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js) configuration, I intend to log everything to a file in logs/test/log-*timestamp*.txt file and only INFO level to console, but I see that the console prints all the levels. How do I fix this?

```
{
    "appenders": {
        "test": {
            "type": "dateFile",
            "filename": "logs/test/log",
            "pattern": "-yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss.txt",
            "alwaysIncludePattern": true,
            "keepFileExt": true
        },
        "test-filter": {
            "type": "logLevelFilter",
            "appender": "test",
            "level": "trace",
            "maxLevel": "fatal"
        },
        "default": {
            "type": "dateFile",
            "filename": "logs/default",
            "pattern": "-yyyy-MM-dd.txt",
            "alwaysIncludePattern": true,
            "keepFileExt": true
        },
        "console": {
            "type": "console",
            "level": "info",
            "maxLevel": "info"
        }
    },
    "categories": {
        "default": {
            "appenders": [
                "default"
            ],
            "level": "info"
        },
        "test": {
            "appenders": [
                "test-filter",
                "console"
            ],
            "level": "debug"
        }
    }
}
```